# why du -sh outputs wrong size of a memory mapped file?

Tags: c++, linux, mmap, nfs, du

I have created a memory mapped file on NFS (CentOS7).

but **du -sh** shows file size much less than what **ls -la** OR **stat** command is showing.

```
du -sh foo.dat
96M     foo.dat
```

**du -bh** output matches with **ls -la**, **stat** command output.

```
du -bh foo.dat
718M    foo.dat
```

**ls -la** gives correct number of bytes.

```
 ls -la foo.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 david users 752562176 Apr 20 03:58 foo.dat
```

**stat** command output is following

```
stat foo.dat
  File: ‘foo.dat’
  Size: 752562176       Blocks: 196555     IO Block: 131072 regular file
Device: 31h/49d Inode: 26822713    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1035/  david)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2018-04-21 03:55:58.305448765 -0500
Modify: 2018-04-21 03:58:05.293052537 -0500
Change: 2018-04-21 03:58:05.293052537 -0500
 Birth: -
```

I am wondering why **du -sh** reports the wrong size. this is not the case if I create a memory mapped file in /tmp which is a local disk.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: The disk block information won't be updated until the changes are sent to the server, since it depends on the remote filesystem implementation.

Comment: @Barmar this is a programming question. I created the file using mmap and regularly doing msync to sync the contents. du -bh seems to be returning the correct value. My concern here is that, is there any issue using mmap on NFS if the file is not going to be shared among the processes. only single process will read/write to it.

Comment: In general, many assumptions about consistency do not apply when NFS is involved. It's just something you have to live with.

Comment: might be of interest - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102364/why-ls-reports-a-huge-file-and-du-does-not

Comment: @ewcz, thanks for the link. I think du is showing less size because i am creating sparse file. I am not writing it sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

I think du is showing less size because i am creating sparse file. I am not writing it sequentially